# How to make axes more visible on a blueprint?

Tags: modeling

[image]

Hey. I have faced a problem, I don’t know how to make more visible axes on a blueprint. Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Properties* editor > *Object Data* > *Empty*, enable the *Use Alpha* option, you can also play with the transparency.

[image]